# This Page requires javascript. Please enable javascript in your Browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm trying to automate a data checking operation in a webpage(mozilla firefox browser) using the Greasemonkey addOn. When i try to execute this script i get an error like *`"This Page requires javascript. Please enable javascript in your Browser"`* in a new tab even though i enabled the Java script in the browser. Any possible reason/solution for this? My Greasemonkey script is as follows.

> // ==UserScript==
>
> // @name          Webmonkey's Hello World
>
> // @namespace     http://www.webmonkey.com
>
> // @description
>
> // @include
>   http://www1.url.net/hydromet_dms/report_rainfall/show_rf_data_datetime_range
>
> // ==/UserScript==
>
> document.getElementById("txt_station_num").value = "5000";// **thisworks** 
>   document.getElementById("form1").submit();//**But this wont
>   work.**

HTML part:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate_station();" value="Show Data" name="submit_param">
```

Comment: please poste also the corresponding html part. are you sure the form id=form1 is valid ?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure that the id=form1 is valid.

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="return validate_station();" value="Show Data" name="submit_param">

Comment: I cannot "guess" anything since there is only parts of the code :/ you can edit your question, provide enough html code so others can test with jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

which will submit the first form.

You can also loop through the array to see which one you need.

Comment: It's responding to document.forms[0].submit(); only with error. But not for other Forms.

Comment: did you try using events like window.onload in case your script runs too early?

Comment: I tried these two, but it didn't help me.

window.document.onload = function(){ 
    window.document.forms[0].submit(); 
});

window.onload = function(){ 
       window.document.forms[0].submit(); 
});

Answer (score 0):

The form you are trying to submit uses Javascript, and by calling submit in this way, you're bypassing Javascript processing. See [MDN's page about form.submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit).

To get around this, you could try simulating a click event on the submit button instead of directly calling submit on the form.

Comment: I tried simulating click event but it doesn't helped me.